How to keep the updates applied in a payload iterating in a map
I Have a issue in my code and I dont know how to solved, I explaint the situation, I have two arrays of objects; The Payload we need to do a loop and if it math with an item in the array named Available, we need to subtrac the qty of this match with the value in the loop for example this number (61327) come from payload and exists in available if the qty from the payload is equal or less to the qty in available array we substract the value in available if not we does not nothing, we keeping the result in memory for the next iterator.
Available
[
  {
    "number": "61327",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6010550",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6010482",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6228245",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6076532",
    "qty": 1
  }
]

Payload
[
  {
    "number": "61327",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6010550",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6010482",
    "qty": 1
  }
]

Code
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun updateValueFromAvailable( list, sku, qty ) = list  map ( itm, idx ) -> (if ( itm.number ~= sku ) itm update { case .wms_qty -> itm.wms_qty - qty } else itm )

---

payload map do {

    var result = updateValueFromAvailable( available, $.number, $.qty )

    ---
    $
}

I don't know if is possible omitted the call of result or has another way to run the function to update without call it
Current Result from available does not keep the updates in the next iteration
[
  [
    {
      "number": "61327",
      "wms_qty": 0,
      "item_id": "61327"
    },
    {
      "number": "6010550",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6010550"
    },
    {
      "number": "6010482",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6010482"
    },
    {
      "number": "6228245",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6228245"
    },
    {
      "number": "6076532",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6076532"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "number": "61327",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "61327"
    },
    {
      "number": "6010550",
      "wms_qty": 0,
      "item_id": "6010550"
    },
    {
      "number": "6010482",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6010482"
    },
    {
      "number": "6228245",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6228245"
    },
    {
      "number": "6076532",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6076532"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "number": "61327",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "61327"
    },
    {
      "number": "6010550",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6010550"
    },
    {
      "number": "6010482",
      "wms_qty": 0,
      "item_id": "6010482"
    },
    {
      "number": "6228245",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6228245"
    },
    {
      "number": "6076532",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6076532"
    }
  ]
]

Expected Result One result keeping the updates in all the iterations
 [
    {
      "number": "61327",
      "wms_qty": 0,
      "item_id": "61327"
    },
    {
      "number": "6010550",
      "wms_qty": 0,
      "item_id": "6010550"
    },
    {
      "number": "6010482",
      "wms_qty": 0,
      "item_id": "6010482"
    },
    {
      "number": "6228245",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6228245"
    },
    {
      "number": "6076532",
      "wms_qty": 1,
      "item_id": "6076532"
    }
  ]

I only show you the behavior that I hope the arrangement available during the payload loop has in memory.
Sincerely!

The script doesn't create the actual output. Please review and clarify the question.

Also the logic that you are trying to apply is not clear. Please add more detail and correct the syntax. Salutations and thanks should be removed per the guidelines.

In addition to what has been pointed out, what do you mean by iteration? Do you mean a new request / message? or is it running in something like a for-each scope and you need to store the value for the next item?

The logic is not fully clear from the question but there are no loops or iterators in DataWeave that you can 'update' the status from the previous iteration. You need to think your script in terms of map or reduce operations. Reduce will apply an expression to each item of an array and let you update the status of the last expression, so it is the appropriate function to use.
You can simplify the condition by using a conditional update instead of an if. It also helps to express better the intention of the code. I also added the missing condition for qty.
%dw 2.0
var available = [
  {
    "number": "61327",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6010550",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6010482",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6228245",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6076532",
    "qty": 1
  }
]

fun updateValueFromAvailable(list, sku, qty) =
    list 
        map ((item) -> 
            item update {
                case .qty if(item.number == sku and item.qty <= qty) -> item.qty - qty
            }
        )

output application/json  
---
payload reduce ((item, accumulator = available) -> 
    updateValueFromAvailable(accumulator, item.number, item.qty)
)

Output
[
  {
    "number": "61327",
    "qty": 0
  },
  {
    "number": "6010550",
    "qty": 0
  },
  {
    "number": "6010482",
    "qty": 0
  },
  {
    "number": "6228245",
    "qty": 1
  },
  {
    "number": "6076532",
    "qty": 1
  }
]

As a side note, use full names for keys when possible. Clarity and intention are much more valuable in code that having to type one less letter.
Also note that you can omit optional arguments of map() or mapObject() if you don't need to use them.
